# Prove that a solution for non homogeneous equation is bounded

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider $$x'=Ax+g(t)$$

for some $g(t):\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n.$ Assume that $A$ is hyperbolic i.e it has no eigenvalues on the imaginary axis. Assume that $g(t)$ is uniformally continuous and bounded. Verify that $$x(t)=e^{At}P_sv+\int_0^te^{A(t-\tau)}P_sg(\tau)d \tau-\int_0^{\infty} e^{A(t- \tau)}P_u g(\tau) d\tau$$
is a sulotion for any $v \in \mathbb{R}^n.$ What is the initial condition? and prove that the solution is bounded.

I differentiate $x(t)$ but still having a problem with show it equals to $Ax+g(t)$, what I have is $$ x'(t)=Ae^{At}P_sv+e^{A(t-\tau)}P_sg(t)+\int_0^tAe^{A(t-\tau)}P_sg(\tau)d \tau-\int_0^{\infty} Ae^{A(t- \tau)}P_u g(\tau) d\tau- e^{A{(t-\tau)}}P_u g(t) $$
$$=A[e^{At}P_sv+\int_0^te^{A(t-\tau)}P_sg(\tau)d \tau-\int_0^{\infty} Ae^{A(t- \tau)}P_u g(\tau) d\tau]+g(t)[e^{A(t-\tau)}P_s -e^{A{(t-\tau)}}P_u]=Ax+g(t)[e^{A(t-\tau)}P_s -e^{A{(t-\tau)}}P_u]$$
I am getting stuck here. Also in the part of showing that is actually bounded

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: What is $P_s$ ?

Comment: An operator with range $\mathbb{E}^s$ that is the set of eignevalue that makes the solution stable